# Error in busybox cross-compilation to arm

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to compile busybox for arm on my x86_64 desktop, using buildroot 2012.11.
I think my buildroot build config was correct :

The file is on pastebin for readability and spacing reasons : http://pastebin.com/tSZvcEqe

Still, when i try to compile, i get this error (apparently something is wrong with the "rlimit-fsize" system variable.

```
  CC      loginutils/passwd.o
loginutils/passwd.c: In function ‘passwd_main’:
loginutils/passwd.c:104:16: error: storage size of ‘rlimit_fsize’ isn’t known
loginutils/passwd.c:188:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘setrlimit‘ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
loginutils/passwd.c:188:12: error: ‘RLIMIT_FSIZE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
loginutils/passwd.c:188:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
loginutils/passwd.c:104:16: warning: unused variable ‘rlimit_fsize’ [-Wunused-variable]
make[1]: *** [loginutils/passwd.o] Error 
make: *** [loginutils] Error 2
```

Following is the busybox build config file :

```
#
# Automatically generated make config: don't edit
# Busybox version: 1.20.2
# Mon Dec 10 21:45:20 2012
#
CONFIG_HAVE_DOT_CONFIG=y

#
# Busybox Settings
#

[...]


#
# Login/Password Management Utilities
#
CONFIG_ADD_SHELL=y
CONFIG_REMOVE_SHELL=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_SHADOWPASSWDS=y
CONFIG_USE_BB_PWD_GRP=y
CONFIG_USE_BB_SHADOW=y
CONFIG_USE_BB_CRYPT=y
CONFIG_USE_BB_CRYPT_SHA=y
CONFIG_ADDUSER=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_ADDUSER_LONG_OPTIONS=y
# CONFIG_FEATURE_CHECK_NAMES is not set
CONFIG_FIRST_SYSTEM_ID=100
CONFIG_LAST_SYSTEM_ID=999
CONFIG_ADDGROUP=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_ADDGROUP_LONG_OPTIONS=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_ADDUSER_TO_GROUP=y
CONFIG_DELUSER=y
CONFIG_DELGROUP=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_DEL_USER_FROM_GROUP=y
CONFIG_GETTY=y
CONFIG_LOGIN=y
# CONFIG_LOGIN_SESSION_AS_CHILD is not set
# CONFIG_PAM is not set
CONFIG_LOGIN_SCRIPTS=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_NOLOGIN=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_SECURETTY=y
CONFIG_PASSWD=y
# CONFIG_FEATURE_PASSWD_WEAK_CHECK is not set
CONFIG_CRYPTPW=y
CONFIG_CHPASSWD=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_DEFAULT_PASSWD_ALGO="des"
CONFIG_SU=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_SU_SYSLOG=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_SU_CHECKS_SHELLS=y
CONFIG_SULOGIN=y
CONFIG_VLOCK=y

[...]
```

Other than that, the host system is an up-to-date archlinux x86_64 desktop 
    Linux samhildanach 3.6.9-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Dec 4 08:04:10 CET 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks like you may be missing some header files used in passwd.c.  Confirm if you have all the header files listed.  If the files are available make sure the path to the headers are included in your PATH variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, found the answer here : 
http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2012-May/077766.html

Just apply the patch in the message, or edit the `include/libbb.h` so that it inlcudes  (it should have a line at the top, between the other includes, saying `#include <sys/resource.h>`)
Thanks for you help though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed in Buildroot through commit http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/commit/package/busybox/busybox-1.20.2/busybox-1.20.2-sys-resource.patch?id=6fce747d08437fc35d67b69631254faf3982db69. This commit was part of the 2012.11 version of Buildroot, which was released last December.